# How to display first column and row only?

Tags: java

I have created a multiplication table. However, it cannot display the first row and column with my code. Is this even achievable via loop? Herr is my code:

```
int a;
int b;

for (a=1; a<=3; a++)
{
    for (b=1; b<=3; b++)
    {
        System.out.print(a*b + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The output of this code is:

```
1 2 3
2 4 6
3 6 9
```

However, i want the 123 on a row and column to display only. Is this achievable?

Desired output:

```
1 2 3
2
3
```

Comment: If I understand you correct: Only run your inner loop if `a==1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic approach is to know where your outer loop is at and print accordingly to your desired result.

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a;
        int b;

        for (a=1; a<=3; a++)
        {
            // Only print the first row
            if (a == 1) {
                for (b=1; b<=3; b++)
                {
                    System.out.print(a*b + " ");
                }
                // Ends the first row 
                System.out.println("");
            } else {
                // Prints the rest of the first column
                System.out.println(a);
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1 2 3 
2
3
```

### UPDATE

If I understand your comment, here's an approach with just one loop.  It assumes that the size of the row will equal the size of the column.  This means that the number of digits you'll display will be an odd number `(rowColLength * 2 - 1)` which makes the first digit a pivot point.

```
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 0;
        int rowColLength = 3;
        int numberOfDigits = rowColLength * 2 - 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfDigits; i++) {
            if (i < rowColLength) {
                // Prints the first row
                System.out.print(++a + " ");
            } else if (i == rowColLength){
                // Decrements the last number from the first row 
                // to continue the column count for printing
                System.out.print("\r\n" + --a);
            } else {
                // Prints the rest of the column
                System.out.print("\r\n" + ++a);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
1 2 3 
2
3
```

Comment: I see your code works but i have to work hard on how to understand nested loops more. Its kinda difficult for me to understand this. Thank you though. Impressive

Comment: @KatieSerenVera The outer loop is meant to print each line of your results.  The if statement inside of the outer loop controls whether to print the rest of the row, or only print the first column.

Comment: Not for understanding the nested loop but for code refactoring, you probably don't need a nested loop for special cases like this. You can potentially rewrite it so that: 1) print the first line (inner loop) with b. 2) start the for loop from 2 and display the row 2 - 3 of column 1. End result: 2 independent loops.

Comment: @KatieSerenVera See updates I've added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the upper bounds to be limited.
Better readable would be:

```
int rows = 3; // 1?
int columns = 10; // 1?
for (int row = 1; row <= rows; ++row) {
    for (int column = 1; column <= columns; ++column) {
        System.out.printf("%3d", row * column);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The `printf` prints digits, padded to the left upto 3 positions with spaces.

If you want a header row and column à la Excel:

```
// Header row:
System.out.print("AxB ");
for (int column = 1; column <= columns; ++column) {
    System.out.printf("%3d", column);
}
System.out.println();
System.out.print("---|");
for (int column = 1; column <= columns; ++column) {
    System.out.print("---");
}
System.out.println();

// Data rows
for (int row = 1; row <= rows; ++row) {
    System.out.printf("%3d|", row); // Column header
    for (int column = 1; column <= columns; ++column) {
        System.out.printf("%3d", row * column);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print header and columns labels in 2 different loops:

```
  int a;
  int b;

  // Print header label
  for (b=1; b<=3; b++) {
    System.out.print(b + " ");
  }
  System.out.println();
  // Print column label
  for (b=2; b<=3; b++) {
    System.out.println(b);
  }
```

The output:

```
1 2 3 
2
3
```

Answer (score -1):

Several possibilities, you could for example save the result to a variable and not print it if bigger than 3.

```
int temp = a*b
if (temp < 4){
     System.out.print(temp);
else {
     System.out.print(" ");
}
```